# 100% screen width not working properly in Salesforce1 on iPhone

Tags: salesforce1-app, css, ios

I'm working on an app for Salesforce1. S1 has a menu on the left and a news feed on the right, both hidden until revealed by swiping the screen to the left or right.

My body width is set to 100%, but when I swipe to the left or the right, the content slides from side to side but the actual screen does not, as if the content is floating around inside the body. This only occurs on the iPhone. On Android, the 100% width works perfectly.

If I give my body a width of 310px, it swipes fine.

Would anyone have any suggestions or advice?

```
     html,body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            min-width:310px;
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: #000;
            font: normal 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;     
            font-size: 12px;
     }

    .content{
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Try setting the viewport meta tag - Details on tag: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html - Details on how to set in visualforce: http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/12/visualforce-html5-mobile.html